# ¿Por qué cuando intento hacer cout de la variable me sale 0?

Tags: c++

Este codigo es para programar una secuencia de numeros entre un rango A y B que basicamente pide que con la formula n = n + Div(n) en donde Div(n) saca el total de los numeros divisores de ese numero hasta que n sea menor o igual a B.

El problema que tengo es que al intentar de hacer cout en i me sale 0 por lo que creo que no funciona bien el while, desconozco el error asi que si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceria.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int DivisoresN(int nAnterior) 
{
    int Div=0;
    for(int y=0;y<=nAnterior;y++){
        if(nAnterior%y==0){
            Div++;
        }
    }
    return Div;
}

int main(){
    int c,a,n=a,b;
    cin>>c;
    for(int x=0;x<c;x++){
        cin>>a; 
        cin>>b;
        
        int i=0,nAnterior;
        while(n>=a && n<=b){
            nAnterior=n;
            n=nAnterior+DivisoresN(nAnterior); 
            i++;
        }
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: No es como en matemáticas que al decir que `x = y` el valor va a ser siempre el mismo. El problema es que `n` tiene un valor indeterminado. Las variables en C++ no tienen un valor por defecto, necesitas darles un valor inicial. Tampoco sé cuál es valor que `n` debería tener así que revisa eso.